# How to invoke RPM as service

Tags: rpmbuild

How to start or invoke a service from RPM after installing it.

As I have rpm package and installed  it using `rpm -ivh pidgin-2.7.9-5.el6.2.i686.rpm`, now I want to invoke the rpm automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot "invoke an rpm"; an rpm just installs certain files on your system. That does not even mean that any of those files is executable. The command to launch the application will also always be different (systemctl, init.d, just launch the binary, ...).